# How do I add row indices to a column using lambda functions in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

**Original dataframe**:

|  | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aT | 1 |
| 1 | bee | 2 |
| 2 | cT | 3 |
| 3 | Y | 4 |
| 4 | D | 5 |

I would like to combine each item in the "index" column (except items trailing with T), hyphen (-) and row number like this:

**Expected result**:

|  | Index | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | aT | 1 |
| 1 | bee-1 | 2 |
| 2 | cT | 3 |
| 3 | Y-3 | 4 |
| 4 | D-4 | 5 |

My code is the following:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"Index": ["aT", "bee", "cT","Y","D"], "Value": [1, 2, 3,4,5]})
ind_name = df.iloc[df.index,0].apply(lambda x: x + '-' + str(df.index) if "T" not in x else x)
```

How to correct my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `.apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Index": ["aT", "bee", "cT", "Y", "D"], "Value": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df['Index'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Index'] + ('' if 'T' in x['Index'] else f'-{x.name}'), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Index  Value
0     aT      1
1  bee-1      2
2     cT      3
3    Y-3      4
4    D-4      5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `pandas.Series.str.endswith` and `str.cat`:

```
s = df["Index"]
df["Index"] = s.where(s.str.endswith("T"), 
                      s.str.cat(df.index.astype(str), "-"))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Index  Value
0     aT      1
1  bee-1      2
2     cT      3
3    Y-3      4
4    D-4      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `loc` with `str.contains` and `+=` instead:

```
>>> df.loc[~df['Index'].str.contains('T'), 'Index'] += '-' + df.index.to_series().astype(str)
>>> df
   Index  Value
0     aT      1
1  bee-1      2
2     cT      3
3    Y-3      4
4    D-4      5
>>>
```

Remember to add `to_series()` so that pandas would be able to detect corresponding indexes and add to them, just a pure `Index` object does not have an index since it's values are the index :)